# How to embed auto-generated English subtitles with either youtube-dl or yt-dlp?

Tags: youtube-dl, subtitle, yt-dlp

The key here is to be able to embed the auto-generated subtitles.
The tool can download the autogenerated subtitles but can only embed the real subtitle file, if it exists. I wondered if there would be a way to embed or capture in the video the auto-generated subs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Emmbed Subtitle To Video

`--embed-subs`: Embed subtitles in the video (only for mp4, webm and mkv videos)

> When --embed-subs and --write-subs are used together, the subtitles are written to disk and also embedded in the media file. You can use just --embed-subs to embed the subs and automatically delete the separate file.

don't forget to list the available subtitles using `--list-subs`.

You can find more like this [here](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#subtitle-options)

## Burn Subtitles To Video

Burn subtitles into the video is also an easy step. You can do this just using commonly used VLC Media Player and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/). I found a great video about this. you can do this with just 4 easy steps by following this video

Comment: Thank you! I see what this does. I probably meant: BURN subtitles into the video. Is there such option?

Comment: @Adel first of all thanks for asking some more... this code says "embed subtitles t video" means the subtitles will first downloaded into the disk and then it will attach subtitles to media file after attacing the source file will be deleted. In simply means you dont need to carry .srt or .vtt along with video..... It will work same as you ask

Comment: Thanks, so it embeds so we can select to show them or not from the video player menu. However, I want to burn them into the frames of the video to be always visible. Is this a possibility? Thank you.

Comment: @Adel i suggest you this one (adding subtitles to video frames permanently) is a bad experience because till now you can change the size of the subtitle if you are using vlc media player but if you done adding to frames then the size cannot be changed and if someone dont want to view the video the option to disable subtitle will not available. i hopw this one clear.

Comment: Thanks, for my purposes I need the added subtitles onto the frames permanently because the situation demands this.

Comment: @Adel oh so this is reason.... dont worry To do this, you will need video editing software that supports subtitle importing and exporting, such as Adobe Premiere Pro or Final Cut Pro. you can take a refernece from my answer thst is updated

Comment: So you can't do it with youtube-dl, that is all i wanted to know

Comment: @Adel you have misconception that the emmbed subtitle are not done by yt-dlp. these type of things are done by ff-mpeg. VLC media player or other softwares uses ffmpeg to done this. you can do it manually by command-line but doing this manually is type of headache. trust me!!! :) but if you want to done it manually go here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo. if you found helpful mark it as accepted and upvoted.